# Vaadin property formatter on form

Tags: java, vaadin

I've a Form where an property of source Item need to be formatter by an custom format.

Source property (of my own bean) is a `Integer`, but need to be formatted as a Currency-like format.

I tried to implement my own `PropertyFormatter`, and setup it inside my `FieldFactory.createField` for this form as

```
TextField tf = new TextField("Price");
tf.setPropertyDataSource(new MyPriceFormatter());
return tf;
```

But as I see from the logs, only `format()` method is called. But `parse()` method is never used, and `setValue` is never called

What's wrong with my code? How to use custom PropertyFomatter for forms? Or how to add custom format for form's field?

---

After some investigation i found that there is something just replaces my formatter, with an new `MethodProperty` data source. So i'd implemented my own `PriceField`, with overrided `setPropertyDataSource`, that fix this situation. btw, it seems to bee hacky, and i'm still looking for an other way

Answer (score 1):

I have also experienced this problem and solved it another way. Actually I also had to make a textfield formated with a currency :-)

The problem is that the datasource in the PropertyFormatter is null at the time you are creating the fields in the FormFieldFactory. You can instead set the datasource on your field after the FormFieldFactory has been called:

```
addCountryRatesForm.setFormFieldFactory(new MyFormFieldFactory());
Field internationalRate = addCountryRatesForm.getField("internationalRate");
internationalRate.setPropertyDataSource(new CurrencyFormatter("#0.00 ", currency, internationalRate.getPropertyDataSource()));
```

So unfortunately with Vaadin you cannot create a TextField that sets its own formatter.